# Best practices to keep state histories

Tags: javascript, vue-component, state, vuex, pushstate

I’m wondering now what is the best practice to keep the history of the component and make it possible to walk forth and back on it.

So far I can see it working like this:

I watch the state change, make a snapshot of it and push it into a store ( I would use indexedDB for that ). Then when I need it I can with shortcuts to walk around it pushing the one I need as a current state.

I would love it hear experienced guys how they solve it. Maybe there are some simple ways but I just don’t know it.

Comment: Checkout the Command pattern. It will allow you to do actions such as Redo and Undo. A plus is that if you keep a journal of "commands", you can then recreate anything since the only thing you need is the initial state and then apply every command that affected such state.